# How to destructure this object?

Tags: reactjs, object

I'm a newbie programmer, and I need some help to destructure the following object. The Colors property from the branding object, I was able to desctructure it correctly. But for the fonts, I really don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

```
branding : {
  colors: {
    primaryColor: '#2e8e71',
    secondaryColor: '#143e31',
    tertiaryColor: '#e96429',
    quaternaryColor: '#15bbdb',
    bgColor: '#e3e3e3',
    error: '',
    warning: '',
    disabled: '',
  },
  fonts:
    [
      {
        font: 'Roboto',
        weight: [400, 500, 700, 900],
        style: 'italic',
        size: ['14px', '1.1em', '2em', '2.3em']
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: show expected results, also show the code you have already written

Comment: destructuring is just syntax sugar, if you want the first font, you'd go for `const [firstFont, secondFont, ...unspecifiedFonts] = fonts`, but if it doesn't feel natural or easy to read, don't destructure :)

Answer (score 1):

To destructure the data you need to specify the keys you wants to extract from the object.

---

For simple keys :

```js
const data = {
  branding: {
    colors: {
      primaryColor: '#2e8e71',
      secondaryColor: '#143e31',
      tertiaryColor: '#e96429',
      quaternaryColor: '#15bbdb',
      bgColor: '#e3e3e3',
      error: '',
      warning: '',
      disabled: '',
    },
    fonts: [{
      font: 'Roboto',
      weight: [400, 500, 700, 900],
      style: 'italic',
      size: ['14px', '1.1em', '2em', '2.3em']
    }]
  },
};

const {
  branding: {
    colors,
    fonts,
  },
} = data;

console.log(fonts);
```

---

For arrays :

When you encounter arrays, in the case of `fonts`, you can also destructure it if you know the number of elements you have in it.

Use the `[]`.

The position of the data is used as reference.

```js
const data = {
  branding: {
    colors: {
      primaryColor: '#2e8e71',
      secondaryColor: '#143e31',
      tertiaryColor: '#e96429',
      quaternaryColor: '#15bbdb',
      bgColor: '#e3e3e3',
      error: '',
      warning: '',
      disabled: '',
    },
    fonts: [{
      font: 'Roboto',
      weight: [400, 500, 700, 900],
      style: 'italic',
      size: ['14px', '1.1em', '2em', '2.3em']
    }]
  },
};

const {
  branding: {
    colors,
    
    fonts: [
      Roboto,
    ],
  },
} = data;

console.log(Roboto);
```

---

As @Icepickle pointed out, to destructure all of the font with specifying only few of them, you can use the following syntax :

```
  const {
    branding: {
      colors,
        
      fonts: [
        Roboto,
        ...otherFonts
      ],
    },
  } = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as follows?

```
const source = {
  branding: {
    colors: {
      primaryColor: '#2e8e71',
      secondaryColor: '#143e31',
      tertiaryColor: '#e96429',
      quaternaryColor: '#15bbdb',
      bgColor: '#e3e3e3',
      error: '',
      warning: '',
      disabled: '',
    },
    fonts: [{
      font: 'Roboto',
      weight: [400, 500, 700, 900],
      style: 'italic',
      size: ['14px', '1.1em', '2em', '2.3em']
    }]
  }
}

const {
  branding: {
    colors,
    fonts
  }
} = source;

const {
  font,
  weight,
  style,
  size,
} = fonts[0];
```